# Making node check files in a second plan

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make a expire key system with nodejs to one app and for check expiration (30 days) I decided use a while loop and checking it, but as I thought, I need another thread to do this, I tried use the worker_thread but gives me "Module did not self-register" at "node_modules\Canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18". There is a way to do this process or still another way to do the keys expire? I'm new to node and I don't have any other ideia.

Obs:. to check if a key is expired, it store the time in millis that the key was got and store another value with the time in millis 30 days after, and do a simple (expireTime - gotTime <= 0)

Comment: Chances are you don't need threads, and what you want to do would be perfectly handled by a `setInterval`, cron job, or another node process.

Comment: @MadWard but it would not freeze the main application?

Comment: It would in the case where the main application consists only of synchronous operations. For example if you're looping and doing calculating on a very large array. Node.js is asynchronous, meaning there is a very high likelihood your use case isn't blocking the event loop, and an interval would be just fine.

Comment: @MadWard it works fine. Thank you.